# Win32 resource string table with format

Tags: string, mfc, resources, format

i have an .rc file in my mfc project as below.

```
STRINGTABLE
BEGIN
    ID_DRAW_ARC             "Draw arc."
    ID_DRAW_BEZIER          "Draw bezier %d count"
END
```

the application showed the string table on the status bar like this

```
'Draw arc.'
'Draw bezier %d count'
```

I want to change second sentence like this

```
'Draw bezier 50 count'
```

How can i this? 
Should I set the message on the status bar by manually with `CStatusBar` Object?

if you have another solution, answer me please.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CString::LoadString` to get strings from resource. Then simply format the text.

```
CString format;
if (format.LoadString(ID_DRAW_BEZIER))
{
    if (format.Find(L"%d") >= 0)
    {
        CString text;
        text.Format(format, 50);
        m_wndStatusBar.SetPaneText(0, text, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: if the operator move the mouse cursor on a menu, the mfc framework change the message on the statusbar. it will include '%d'. how can i catch the moment before change the message?

Comment: look through CFrameWnd::OnCmdMsg or override mouse functions in child window or frame.